Controlling multiple shape keys for different meshes in the same movement
I have a question regarding shape keys. I have 3 different meshes that all move downward at different lengths. They are all part of the same movement but each has its own shape key. Is there a way to control these so that I can more easily adjust how much deeper alla of these 3 meshes go down?
Thanks for any help and tips!
Here is the file: 

Are the shape-key factors the same (or logically related) to one another? Drivers might be a way to go.

Thanks for answering! They are logically related to each other. They are moving down then up! How would you recommend me work with Drivers? :)

I think it would be easiest for folks to give definite answers if you illustrated your specific case.. that would be the easiest way to demonstrate how you might use drivers in general. You can share a representative file, isolating this feature, on https://blend-exchange.com/ , pasting the provided link into your post.

Thank you! I have uploaded the file and provided the link into my post! :)


in all shape key values right click -> clear keyframes except one



in the one left shape key, which is still keyframed, right click and click "copy as new driver"



then right click on all non keyframed shape key values -> paste driver



now, whenever you change the keyframes of your keyframed value, all other will go with it.


Hope that helps.

Thank you Chris!

you are welcome
